# Conditional Probability Question from Diagram

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: you should explain what you have tried. maybe start with an interpretation of the data you have. for example, what does 0.1 mean in that box on the right of the "D"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Bayes network and each table corresponds to some prior or conditional probability. For example, $P(C=c|A=a,D=-d)$ is $0.1$. For your question, we have $$\begin{align}P(C=-c|D=-d)&=1-P(C=c|D=-d)\\&= 1-(P(C=c,A=a|D=-d)+ P(C=c,A=-a|D=-d)) \\&=1-(P(C=c|A=a, D=-d)P(A=a)+ P(C=c|A=-a,D=-d)P(A=-a))\end{align}$$
All the probabilities you need are in the table.